# How to change a jquery ui widget control's height using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using jquery widget in my asp.net webforms. I want to increase the height of the select control to 33px from the default 22px. I see in Google developer too that the height is set as follows:

The height is set here:

```
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button  {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-widget select {
    height: 33px;
}
</style>
```

My html and javascript:

```
<div class="ui-widget"><select id="drpAccountSearch" runat="server" NAME="drpAccountSearch"></select></div>

//Set up the account dropdown as an autocomplete combobox
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#drpAccountSearch" ).combobox();
});
```

But the height doesn't change from 22px to 33px.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `height: 33px !important;`?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() { $( "#drpAccountSearch" ).css('height','33px'); });

Comment: are you sure you assign this id unique for it;I mean not use before this element

Comment: Not used before this element